# need suggestions about content filtering project

Tags: .net, algorithm, firefox, filtering

i'm thinking of designing and implementing a content filtering software as my graduation project. i want it to be a user contributed software. i mean, users can also add/categorize websites. it should be also a web project and extensions for browsers like chrome, firefox, ie..

my question is which programming language do you suggest for this project? i know that firefox extensions are javascript based maybe you can say use .net framework 3.5 because it's better in communication with extensions.

sorry for my bad english..

btw any other suggessions about project will be good..

thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would use django or ruby on rails for the web app.  I personally would use django but both work work just fine.

I've never worked with browser extensions so I can't suggest anything for that.